# how to find two sentences which have the largest number of common words?

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of sentences, find two sentences which have the largest number of common words. 
The common words does not need locate in the same position in the sentences( order does not matter).

Thanks !

update:

Does non-pairwise algorithm for this problem exist? Because pairwise is very straightforward.

my idea is to use inverted index to store where this word appears. This need traverse every word in each sentence. And then create a n*n 2D array which is used to count how many times two sentences appear in same bucket in inverted index.

Comment: You are likely to receive much better answers if you show [what have you tried.](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @axiom, I have added my thought. Because I think it is not efficient enough, I did not say at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have an array of sentences:

```
String[] sentences
```

Create some variables which contain default values to keep track of the two sentences with the most common words

```
sentence1Index = -1
sentence2Index = -1
maxCount = -1
```

Do a nested loop on sentences array

```
for i : 0 -> sentences.length
    for j : 0 -> sentences.length
```

Make sure you aren't checking the same sentence

```
  if i != j
```

Split the Strings by empty space (which will usually give you each word assuming you count some symbols as words)

```
  String[] words1 = sentences[i].splitAt(" ")
  String[] words2 = sentences[j].splitAt(" ")
```

Create a temporary count value for this run

```
  tempCount = 0
```

Loop between two word arrays (gotten from the two sentences you are comparing)

```
  for a : 0 -> words1 .length
      for b : 0 -> words2.length
```

If the word is the same, then increment temp count

```
          if words[a] equal-to-ignore-case words[b]
              tempCount++
```

After finishing comparing words, if the tempCount is greater than current maxCount, update all values that keep track of you are looking for

```
  if tempCount > maxCount
      sentence1Index = i
      sentence2Index = j
      maxCount = tempCount
```

Return newly created array which the two sentences

```
if sentence1Index != -1 and sentence2Index  != -1
    String[] retArray =   sentences[sentence1Index], sentences[sentence2Index ]
    return retArray

return null
```

All pseudo code:

```
String[] sentences
sentence1Index = -1
sentence2Index = -1
maxCount = -1

for i : 0 -> sentences.length
    for j : 0 -> sentences.length
      if i != j
          String[] words1 = sentences[i].splitAt(" ")
          String[] words2 = sentences[j].splitAt(" ")
          tempCount = 0
          for a : 0 -> words1 .length
              for b : 0 -> words2.length
                  if words[a] equal-to-ignore-case words[b]
                      tempCount++
          if tempCount > maxCount
              sentence1Index = i
              sentence2Index = j
              maxCount = tempCount

if sentence1Index != -1 and sentence2Index  != -1
    String[] retArray =   sentences[sentence1Index], sentences[sentence2Index ]
    return retArray

return null
```

Comment: your method is brute force. what I am seeking is a more efficient way.

Comment: @city You hadn't mentioned what you tried before this post....nor shown what you've tried

Comment: I am sorry about that. I am a little lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need a method that will take two of the sentences and determine how many words they have in common. This could work by taking the two sentences given as input, and creating from it two arrays containing the words in alphabetical order. Then you can examine the two arrays, advancing forward whichever array comes alphabetically earlier (so if the current match is "abacus" and "book", you would move "abacus" to the next word). If you have a match ("book" and "book"), then you increment a count of matched words, and move both arrays to the next word. You continue to do this until you reach the end of one of the arrays (since the remainder of words in the other array won't have any matches).

Once you have this algorithm implemented, you will need a loop that will look as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < sentenceCount - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < sentenceCount; j++) {
    }
}
```

Inside the loop you will call your function that calculates the number of words in common using the sentences at indexes `i` and `j`. You will keep track of the most number of words in common seen up to that point, and the two sentences where it was found. If a new sentence has a higher number of words in common, you will store that count and the two sentences that yielded that count. At the end, you'll have the two sentences that you want.